# redirecting to Wordpress installed in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I have wordpress installed at `/demo/wp`
I want it to be fetched when I het

```
example.com
```

or `www.example.com`

how can I do it?
I don't know .htaccess

any help is appreciated...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually pretty simple.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^webmonopolist\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.webmonopolist.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ demo/wp [L]
```

This should get the desired effect. You just need to change the domain name.

Full explanation [HERE](http://chanon.info/change-main-domain-to-subfolder/399/)

Comment: thanks for your help, unfortunately not working for me

Comment: this should go to wp installation instead located at /demo/wp

Comment: nopes :( yet not working...you can check the url, I just pasted above

Comment: Remove the index.html and the redirect works. On that index.html file, add this code to the head `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://webmonopolist.com/" />`

Comment: I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: thanks bro..I got it working..have to edit wp config